# how to create age groups in rstudio with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-analysis

how to create age groups in rstudio with dplyr, before 1 year, between 1 and 4 years, between 15 and 29 years, between 30 and 59 years and after 59 years. After that, I have the mortality rate variable and I want to know what the mortality rate is by age group.

```
  faixas_etarias <- cut(painel_mortalidade$idade, 
                        breaks = c(0, 1, 4, 15, 30,60), 
                        labels = c("Antes de 1 ano", "1 a 4 anos", 
                                   "15 a 29 anos", "30 a 59 anos", "Depois de 59 anos"))
  df_mortalidade <- painel_mortalidade %>% 
    mutate(faixas_etarias) %>% 
    filter(perc_cobert_sf > 0) %>% 
    group_by(faixas_etarias, ano, idade) %>% 
    summarise(tx_mortalidade_idade = mean(tx_mortalidade))
```

I tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: Try with `painel_mortalidade$faixas_etarias <- ` or in `mutate` to add the age group column to your dataframe.

Comment: Your `mutate` should be `mutate(faixas_etarias = cut(idade, 
                        breaks = c(0, 1, 4, 15, 30,60), 
                        labels = c("Antes de 1 ano", "1 a 4 anos", 
                                   "15 a 29 anos", "30 a 59 anos", "Depois de 59 anos")))`